# Contour Plot resolutions

Tags: plotting

[image]I am trying to contour plot three curves on Mathematica and one of them is indeterminate for x=0 which seems to cause a big gap in my curve... I have tried everything, from increasing plot points to 800, increasing max recursion to 6 but I can't get a smoother curve... Can anyone help me? Here is an example of my many tries.

```
    ContourPlot[{-(1/2) y (-3 + 3 Sqrt[1 - x^2] y^2 + Sqrt[3] x y 3) == 
    0, (-1 + x^2) (Sqrt[1 - x^2] ((3/2) (y^2 Sqrt[1 - x^2] - 1)/(x (1 -               
    4))) - y^2 (-6 x + ((3/2) (y^2 Sqrt[1 - x^2] - 1)/(x (1 - 4))) + 
    2 Sqrt[3] y 3))/(2 y^2) == 0, y^4 == 1 - x^2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 
    2}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel ->
    {Style[TraditionalForm[Row[{HoldForm[x]}]], 25], 
    Style[TraditionalForm[Row[{HoldForm[y]}]], 25]}, 
    RotateLabel -> False, ImageSize -> Large, 
    FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[26], PlotPoints -> 200, 
    MaxRecursion -> 2, Method -> {MaxBend -> 0.5}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 25], 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[Black], 
    ContourStyle -> {{Darker[Red], Thick}, {Darker[Blue], Thick}, 
    {Black, Thick}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All,
    Exclusions -> None]
```

How do I remove just the line in x==0? Because that is actually an indetermination in the system...

Comment: Would you please add the code so that other users can perform experiments with it?

Comment: Probably adding the option `Exclusions->None` will help.

Comment: The code is on the attached picture

Comment: Please post in text form. Surely you don't expect folks to retype all that..

Comment: I have already posted it

Comment: The intersection are given by `Solve[{-(1/2) y (-3 + 3 Sqrt[1 - x^2] y^2 + Sqrt[3] x y 3) == 0, 
   y^4 == 1 - x^2, -1 <= x <= 1, 0 < y < 2}, {x, y}] // Simplify`

Answer (score 3):

If you define the troublesome curve as function, then it is easy to restrict it to positive values of `x` and there is no need to use `Show`.

```
f[x_, y_] /; x > 0 :=
   (x^2 - 1) *
     (Sqrt[1 - x^2] ((3/2) (y^2 Sqrt[1 - x^2] - 1)/(-3 x)) - 
       y^2 (-6 x + ((3/2) (y^2 Sqrt[1 - x^2] - 1)/(-3 x)) + 6 y Sqrt[3]))/(2 y^2)
```

Then the plot can be made as follows:

```
ContourPlot[
  {-(1/2) y (-3 + 3 Sqrt[1 - x^2] y^2 + Sqrt[3] x y 3) == 0,
   f[x, y] == 0,
   y^4 == 1 - x^2},
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2},
  PlotPoints -> 30,
  ContourLabels -> None]
```

[image: contours]

Answer (score 0):

one trick that helps here is to separately plot the troublesome function only on the range `x>0`:

```
Show[{
  ContourPlot[{-(1/2) y (-3 + 3 Sqrt[1 - x^2] y^2 + Sqrt[3] x y 3) == 
     0, y^4 == 1 - x^2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Black, Green}], 
  ContourPlot[(-1 + 
       x^2) (Sqrt[
         1 - x^2] ((3/2) (y^2 Sqrt[1 - x^2] - 1)/(x (1 - 4))) - 
       y^2 (-6 x + ((3/2) (y^2 Sqrt[1 - x^2] - 1)/(x (1 - 4))) + 
          2 Sqrt[3] y 3)) == 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 200, PlotRange -> All]}, 
 ContourStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

this gives a continuous curve even without `PlotPoints` , adding points makes it smoother though.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for the help!